# Using mongoose findbyid with express to get object from database only works with callback? Callbacks importance in newer js frameworks?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, callback

I'm doing the express local library tutorial on MDN docs and wanted to experiment returning an object without using a call back method.

When passing in the request object parameter for the id to the the findById mongoose method like so `var bookinstance = BookInstance.findById(req.params.id);` and log to the console, this is the contents of bookinstance:

`BookInstance.findOne({ _id: '63e17d2395d1d4e11604cf22' })`

When passing the id and a callback function to the findById method like so

```
BookInstance.findById(req.params.id, function(err, instance) {
      if (err) {
         next(err);
      }
      console.log('findById callback: ' + instance);
      res.render("bookinstance_delete", {
         title: "Book Instance Delete",
         id: instance._id,
         imprint: instance.imprint,
         book: instance.book
      })
   })
```

and log to console, the expected book instance object is outputted:

```
findById callback: {
  _id: new ObjectId("63e17d2395d1d4e11604cf22"),
  book: new ObjectId("63e17d2395d1d4e11604cf16"),
  imprint: 'New York Tom Doherty Associates, 2016.',
  status: 'Available',
  due_back: 2023-02-06T22:20:19.928Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

Is this something to do with javascript in general? This is the first time i've been exposed to express, node, mongoose, and all these javascript based frameworks and technologies, and they all seem to use callbacks quite heavily. Is the purpose of callbacks just to have a way to say, hey execute this task, and when you're finished, do this task?

When I didn't use the call back, the object returned is the object and method(findone), when executed, would give me the bookinstance object and properties. So the callback function would take that object as the instance parameter, execute it and return the object? Is that what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Callbacks are an important part of the JavaScript Language. In traditional synchronous programming each line of the code is thought of as a sequence of successive steps. Each one blocking the next one until they complete their task. Conceptually this is easy to write, follow and debug.

However, in asynchronous programming, tasks don't need to wait for each line of code to complete before another line of code can begin. For example, why should your program have to wait for a database query to finish so that you can read from a file, or upload an image. Surely these time consuming task can be done concurrently? In synchronous programming the time it takes these tasks to complete is added together but in asynchronous programming you can do them concurrently, and so you should.

But then comes the issue of knowing when each asynchronous task is complete. In synchronous programming your code would just move to the next line of code. In JavaScript/Node.js asynchronous programming there is the callback, which
in essence, is simply another function that is invoked with the result of the
asynchronous operation.

You seemed to have grasped this concept:

> so the purpose of callbacks just to have a way to say, hey execute this task, and when you're finished, do this task?

The Callback pattern is just one of several design patterns in JavaScript and can handle asynchronous tasks, but they have their down sides - [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/).

In modern Node.js we have newer design patterns that can handle Control Flow with [Promises](https://web.dev/promises/) and [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await). These have a much nicer syntax and are easier to read, write and debug. Since Node.js is [single threaded](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/node-js-architecture-single-threaded-event-loop) these newer design patterns make it more straightforward to run a responsive web application that doesn't [block the single thread](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop).

Your example above using the callback pattern:

```
BookInstance.findById(req.params.id, function(err, instance) {...});
```

is a very dated approach and all documentation you will find these days outlines the `Promises` or `async/await` pattern.

As an aside, the mongoose [findById](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.findById()) method triggers the [findOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.findOne()) method, which is why you saw `BookInstance.findOne({ _id: '63e17d2395d1d4e11604cf22' })`.

Although mongoose queries are not Promises you can still use the Promises implementation with `then` and `catch` blocks:

```
BookInstance.findById(req.params.id).then((doc) => {
   console.log('Found Instance: ', doc);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

And this is with the `async/await` pattern:

```
app.get('/books/:id', async (req, res) => { // < Note the use of async keyword
   try {
      const result = await BookInstance.findById(req.params.id); // < Note the use of await keyword
      console.log(result);
   } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
   }
});
```

A gotcha with mongoose and Node.js in general you will find is that if you don't use the `Promises` or `async/await` pattern when making database queries is that you will experience unexpected results. For example you wrote:

> When I didn't use the call back, the object returned is the object and method(findone),

This might work for one small query but if you had thousands, or millions of documents in a collection and you performed a query on them your script might actually end before the query has completed and no documents will be returned. It might take 200ms to run the query but your script only took 150ms to run from start to finish. Without a callback, or Promise or async/await your code would just move to the end and you won't get the result from the databse.